# Query wp.comments by user role

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

Trying to query user comments by specific user role. The idea is to display comments by user group/user role  only.  The code below shows all existing user comments but doesn't filter by user roles.

```
$query = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT *
            FROM $wpdb->comments c
            LEFT JOIN $wpdb->commentmeta cm ON c.comment_ID = cm.comment_id
            LEFT JOIN $wpdb->users u ON c.user_id = u.ID
            WHERE c.comment_post_ID = %s
            AND c.comment_approved = 1
            ORDER BY c.comment_ID $comment_order
            ",$post->ID);

        $comments = $wpdb->get_results($query);
```

I feel like I need to insert something like this into the above query

```
ON wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id 
WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' 
AND wp_usermeta.meta_value LIKE '%".$user_rol->roles[0]."%'
```

Comment: Do you want comments from users of specific roles only. Or comments grouped by User roles?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: from specific roles only